# How to remove integer from list?

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to remove integer from integer arraylist. I have no problem with strings and other objects. But when i removing, integer is treated as an index instead of object.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(300);
list.remove(300);
```

When I am trying to remove 300 i am getting: 
`06-11 06:05:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(856): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 300, size is 3`

Comment: Have you checked the docs for `ArrayList`?

Comment: `list.remove(300);` here 300 treated as primitive `int`, pass `Integer` Object.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is normal, there are two versions of the `.remove()` method for lists: one which takes an integer as an argument and removes the entry at this index, the other which takes a generic type as an argument (which, at runtime, is an `Object`) and removes it from the list.

And the lookup mechanism for methods always picks the more specific method first...

You need to:

```
list.remove(Integer.valueOf(300));
```

in order to call the correct version of `.remove()`.

Answer (score 11):

Use indexof to find the index of the item.

```
list.remove(list.indexOf(300));
```

Comment: While this does work, it will be much more expensive to execute than using `Integer.valueOf` to simply get an object.

Comment: It absolutely will ;)

Comment: Why is this getting upvoted when it clearly is not the right way to do it?

Comment: That's SO for you. It's seemingly not wrong enough.

Answer (score 5):

Try (passing an `Integer`, object, instead of an `int`, primitive) -

```
list.remove(Integer.valueOf(300));
```

to invoke the right method - [`List.remove(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code to remove integer from list,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> lIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        lIntegers.add(1);
        lIntegers.add(2);
        lIntegers.add(300);
        lIntegers.remove(new Integer(300));
        System.out.println("TestClass.main()"+lIntegers);
}
```

If you remove item by passing primitive then it will take it as index and not value/object

Answer (score 1):

```
Use list.remove((Integer)300);
```

Comment: I did test it.And worked fine with no errors.please explain why this is wrong

Comment: My apologies, I guessed this would not work but apparently autoboxing is slightly more overzealous than I suspected. You are correct; there is no problem.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart thanks. I thought kind of my answer might not a good practice when it was down voting.

Comment: +1 Casting to integer is equivalent to Integer.valueOf.