# If Arraylist of integer type is present. And I want to remove 1st index from it. How it differ by 1st index and value 1

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

Imagine i have
ArrayList al ={1,2,3,4,5};
I want to remove 1st index i will use
al.remove(1).
I want to remove by value which is 1 i will use
al.remove(1).
How JVM understand whether I want to remove 1st index or value=1??
I want to remove by index and by value also.

Comment: It's all about the overloaded remove method. When providing just "1", it's treated as primitive, thus it invokes the remove(int index) method

Comment: Rather than asking folks to imagine things, remember to show real code. Because `ArrayList al ={1,2,3,4,5};` isn't valid java, _nor_ does it tell folks what you're actually doing (are you relying on auto-boxing? Are you building `Integer` objects explicitly?). As for how the JVM knows: it doesn't, but the compiler does. Java is a strongly typed language, and when you write `remove(1)` the compiler resolves that to the `remove(int)` method.

Comment: related: [How to remove integer from list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037583/how-to-remove-integer-from-list) or  [Properly removing an Integer from a List<Integer>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534146/properly-removing-an-integer-from-a-listinteger) and [*some* more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Barraylist%5D+remove+integer) || you should have completed the [tour]: "***Don't ask about...** Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the JavaDoc for the **List** interface.  Note that `remove()` is an optional method.

**E remove(int index)**

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices). Returns the element that was removed from the list.  Returns the element at the specified position.

**boolean remove(Object o)**

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present (optional operation). If this list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i such that Objects.equals(o, get(i)) (if such an element exists). Returns true if this list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the call).  Returns true if the object existed, false otherwise.

As the methods are presently defined, the method with the argument that best matches the type of parameter is chosen.

Note that if there was only `remove(int index)` and no `remove(Object o)` then calling `remove(int index)` would work whether you specified an `int` or an `Integer`.  In the latter case, `Integer` would be unboxed to an `int`.

BTW, if you are removing one or more consecutive items, starting at index 0, you may as well just assign a sub list to the list since it will be more efficient, especially for large lists.  Say you want to remove the first 10 items.  You can do it like so.

```
list = list.subList(10,list.size());
```

If you keep the original list, then changing anything in the original list or sub list will be reflected in the other since `subList` returns a view of the specified section of the original list.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... How JVM understand whether I want to remove 1st index or value=1?? I want to remove by index and by value also."*

You'll need to specify the argument as an *Integer* object.

```java
al.remove(Integer.valueOf(1));
```

Otherwise, you're right, the *int* value of *1* will be interpreted as an index value.

```java
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
al.remove(Integer.valueOf(1));

System.out.println(al);
```

Output

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thank yu so much.